# Changes in branch after merge in git

Tags: git, github, merge, branch

I have two branches, `foo` and `bar` under `master` in a project that I'm managing with git. Let's suppose I work under `foo` and after being done with it, I merge the changes with `master`. Then I go to `bar` and repeat the process. But then someone tells me there's something I have to change on `foo`, so my first idea was to repeat again, but then I lose all the work done under `bar` branch. How do I achieve my purpose of coming back to a branch and then when I merge with `master` I don't override the changes made under `bar`

I tried creating a new branch for those new changes but if this is the approach, I find the branches a bit useless. But I think git is smart enough to do what I want.

Comment: What do you mean by "Then I go to bar and repeat the process"?  What are you merging to where?  Regarding "I find the branches a bit useless", I think that really depends on your workflow.  It could very well be useless for what you are doing.  But, in a collaborative environment, you'd have things like code reviews and automated tests that would occur for each branch, providing feedback on the change.  Branches are very useful in that kind of environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering with a series of diagrams:

--

create `foo` and `bar` off `master` after commit C:

```
                       foo
                      /
master A ---- B ---- C
                      \
                       bar
```

---

work on `foo` and merge into `master`: (`git checkout master && git merge foo`)

```
foo                    D ---- E ---- F
                      /               \ (merge-commit)
master A ---- B ---- C --------------- G 
                      \
                       bar
```

---

meanwhile, `bar` progressed independently..

```
foo                    D ---- E ---- F
                      /               \
master A ---- B ---- C --------------- G 
                      \
bar                    D' ---- E' ----- F'
```

---

you now wish to update `bar` with changes to `master` (`git pull origin master`)

```
foo                    D ---- E ----------- F
                      /                      \
master A ---- B ---- C ---------------------- G 
                      \                        \
bar                    D' ---- E' ----- F' ---- G' (another merge-commit)
```

---

another change commited on `foo`

```
foo                    D ---- E ----------- F ---- H
                      /                      \
master A ---- B ---- C ---------------------- G 
                      \                        \
bar                    D' ---- E' ----- F' ---- G'
```

---

then, to sync `bar` with new `foo` (`git checkout bar && git pull origin foo`)

```
foo                    D ---- E ----------- F ---- H
                      /                      \      \
master A ---- B ---- C ---------------------- G      \
                      \                        \      \
bar                    D' ---- E' ----- F' ---- G'---- H' (another merge-commit)
```

---

then merge `bar` into `master` (with `master` as active branch, `git merge bar`)

```
foo                    D ---- E ----------- F ---- H
                      /                      \      \
master A ---- B ---- C ---------------------- G -----}-------- I (latest merge-commit)
                      \                        \      \      /
bar                    D' ---- E' ----- F' ---- G'---- H' ---
```

Comment: This looks like the kind of thing I want to do. I will try later and comment. Is `merge-commit` a command? in the last step can you sync with `master` instead of `bar`?

Comment: no `merge-commit` is not a command, but rather a new commit as a result of merging two branches.

Comment: Tried the last step changing `bar` with `master` and didn't get the updates of `foo` in `master`. Any idea why?

Comment: was `foo` pulled into `bar` before the last step?

Comment: I was missing this step. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

> Then I go to bar and repeat the process

Why don't you merge master or foo in bar? That's unclear to me.

> But then someone tells me there's something I have to change on foo, so my first idea was to repeat again, but then I lose all the work done under bar branch.

What do you mean with repeat? Commit you last changes and checkout the other branch.

Also if you made changes that you won't commit you can use git stash for storing the changes temporary.

Please specify your question for more detailed help.

Comment: I wanted to use `master` to have the latest version i.e. the latest commit of every branch. That's my problem, that when I add changes to a branch that's behind `master`, I can't achieve the purpose of merge: to combine (update) `master` branch with the changes made on the other branch

Answer (score 1):

If your `foo` and `bar` branch is not yet deleted, you can rebase

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout foo
git rebase master
git checkout bar
git rebase master
```

But ideally, if your `foo` and `bar` branch is a feature/issue, you should only merge them to master when it's done. If it's too big, break it down to smaller branches (nester or flat).

> I don't override the changes made under bar

this depends on your changes and why care, you merge `bar` branch to `master` anyway. It's none of `bar` business if the work he have done is modify because that feature/fix is done (that's why you merge it). Actually, when you finished a feature/fix branch and merge it master, ideally you delete it cause it's done.